# read and write data to Database simultaneously in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This question has less to do with DB and more to do with general programming.

So I have two models in my flutter application:

1. SingleReminderModel
2. ReminderModel

Now the thing is `ReminderModel` contains a `List<SingleReminderModel>`. Both the `ReminderModel` and every item in `SingleReminderModel` contains their unique `int` id.

Now I can't repeat the ids becuase the new id would just overwrite the data associated with the old id. So I created a new model called `IdModel`. In my DB I save the list of `IdModel`.

So what I need is to simultaneously save data in DB and retrieve it so I can check for the values saved.

Next I have two methods that I need to call `addReminderToDb()` and `scheduleAlarm()`, the names of the methods are self explanatory I guess.

```
Store.instance.setSingleId(id); //saves data to database
Store.instance.getIdData(); // retrieves the List<int>
```

Finally this is my `onSave()` method:

```
  void onSave(
    int? _day,
    DateTime? _workStartTime,
    DateTime? _workEndTime,
    Duration? _frequency,
    Duration? _breakPeriod,
  ) {
    String? _dayName = TimeUtil().returnDayName(_day!);
    DateTime? workStartTime = TimeUtil().getNextDate(_workStartTime, _day);
    DateTime? workEndTime = TimeUtil().getNextDate(_workEndTime, _day);
    Duration? workHour = TimeUtil().returnWorkHour(workStartTime, workEndTime);
    List<DateTime> listOfFrequency = TimeUtil().returnListAlarmTime(
      start: workStartTime,
      end: workEndTime,
      frequency: _frequency!,
      breakPeriod: _breakPeriod!,
    );
    List<SingleReminderModel> singleReminders = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFrequency.length; i++) {
      SingleReminderModel singleReminderModel = SingleReminderModel(
        singleReminderId: i,
        alarmStartAt: listOfFrequency[i],
      );
      singleReminders.add(singleReminderModel);
    }
    ReminderModel? reminder = ReminderModel(
      id: 3, // hardcoded id
      dayName: _dayName,
      workStartTime: _workStartTime,
      workEndTime: _workEndTime,
      workHour: workHour,
      singleReminderModel: singleReminders,
      frequency: _frequency,
      breakPeriod: _breakPeriod,
    );
    scheduleAlarm(singleReminders);
    addReminderToDB(reminder);
  }
```

To rephrase my issue:

I need to save the id for each SingleReminderModel and ReminderModel in IdModel while calling both `addReminderToDb` and `scheduleAlarm()`

Answer (score 0):

Id generation should be handled by the DB provider you are using and retrieved back from the same pipeline, so that it never gets duplicated.

So ideally your onSave should return the actual id generated by the DB provider

Comment: I need to use custom id since flutter_android_alarm_manager requires an ID for each alarm I create and that's why I thought creating custom ID and storing them in separate collection would be easier

Comment: Can you then, set the alarm manager id once id comes back from the DB provider